# symsum on a divergent series

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math

I apologize if I'm asking something trivial. I know that MATLAB's `symsum` (of the Symbolic Math Toolbox) can be used for series. For instance,

```matlab
syms k 
symsum(2^k/factorial(k),k,1,Inf)  % output exp(2) - 1
```

The series whose general term is

[image]

is a divergent one. When I try `symsum` with this series I get

```matlab
symsum(log(k+1)/k,k,1,Inf)
```

That is, MATLAB returns the series unevaluated. However, I wanted a behavior similar to Mathematica's.

```js
Sum[Log[r + 1]/r, {r, 1, Infinity}]
(*Output: During evaluation of In[1]:= Sum::div: Sum does not converge.*)
```

Is it possible to get such an output from MATLAB's Symbolic Math Toolbox?

Comment: Hmmm funny, usually matlab return `∞` or `-∞` if the serie is divergent. I don't know why it's not the case here. +1 for more attention on this question.

Comment: You appear to have a typo in your code relative to the image. Should be `symsum(log((k+1)/k),k,1,Inf)` which returns `Inf` on R2022b.

Comment: Typically when Matlab's Symbolic Toolbox returns the input expression it means that it was unable to evaluate it. This might be be due to divergence but could also be just due to the complexity of the input.